# Perhaps let's eliminate [classification]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms, site-cleanup

[classification](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/classification) has [14 questions](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/classification?sort=newest&pageSize=50) right now, most of which would either fit neatly under [terminology](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) or could just have [classification](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/classification) stripped off.

Of the 14, two actually do deal with classification systems of one kind or another:

- [What do these mineral classification symbols mean?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/35040/what-do-these-mineral-classification-symbols-mean)
- [Is there an open Chemical database that includes GHS/CLP classifications?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/16583/is-there-an-open-chemical-database-that-includes-ghs-clp-classifications)

The first could probably be shoehorned into [terminology](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) or [nomenclature](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nomenclature); it seems like the second is really more of a [reference-request](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request).

**So, I propose the following:**

1. Retagging of one or both of the above questions away from [classification](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/classification); then
2. Disposal of [classification](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/classification), either by

   - (a) Definition as a synonym of [terminology](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology), or
   - (b) Simple deletion

Thoughts?

Comment: Go ahead, remove it manually. I don't  think a synonym would be of much help here. I've retagged the second question already.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Done. Now how does the tag itself get removed?

Comment: If there is no more question that uses the tag, it will get purged the next time the script runs. I am too lazy to look up the meta post, but it's some time around 03:00 UTC (as usual).

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Easy enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Based on uniformly positive early feedback, I went ahead and retagged all of the relevant questions, editing further where warranted.

Comment: If you find yourself removing this tag again, you might want to consider [How should we make tag blacklist requests?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239192/271002)

Comment: @Loong Perhaps, but given how many of the questions were suitable (IMO) for [terminology], going the route of defining it as a synonym therefor would make more sense to me (despite [Mart's comment](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/3516/perhaps-lets-eliminate-classification/3518?noredirect=1#comment4976_3516)).

Comment: @Loong Let's start with step 5 and then do another step 5. After that we should skip steps 1-4 and repeat the procedure. Fun aside, we had [much worse](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/2747/4945) tags, where we went without blacklisting the thing and did not run into trouble. If it really pops up again, just remove it. If this is really getting annoying I agree that we should rather create a synonym (I just thought that isn't necessary here). Now back to step 5.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Many problems can be pleasantly and sufficiently addressed by repeated application of step 5.

Comment: But they would keep coming back after it.

Comment: @M.A.R. Exactly, that's why the ***repeated*** application is necessary. ;-)