# Is [site-cleanup] (Meta tag) worth having?

Tags: discussion, tags

In [this Meta question](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3516/perhaps-lets-eliminate-classification) I went ahead and applied the new Meta [site-cleanup](/questions/tagged/site-cleanup). **Is this a good Meta tag to have?**

It seems like it would be a useful category to be able to search over. In particular, I'm aware of [TRE 1](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2940/the-great-retagging-event-episode-1-the-one-taggers) and [TRE 2](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3113/throw-in-an-idea-for-tre-ii) ([et seq.](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3152/what-time-are-you-in-for-the-tre)) that it would fit onto; perhaps there are others?

Or, will it be too general, or too meta-Meta, or too infrequently used, or ...?

Comment: Poll-style answers are below. Upvote your LIKE or DISLIKE preference!

Comment: I think nobody cares too deeply about tags on meta. That being said, I think it's a good idea to have it. However, I wouldn't propose launching a strike force and add it to every question related. Just have an eye out and start using it from now on.

Comment: You know I always LIKE poll-style stuff. First off, I don't think meta tags are or should be of concern, and second, usually a tag is hardly bad here.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン That sounds suspiciously like you're handing me free rein on Meta........

Answer (score 6):

**If you LIKE the idea of [site-cleanup](/questions/tagged/site-cleanup), UPVOTE THIS ANSWER.**

Answer (score 3):

Whatever you do, please don’t start a retagging marathon!

There is a user over at Travel who is working very *very* hard to fit even the absolute last question that was posted in 2011 and lost relevance two weeks later with the correct tags. Basically, if you go to Travel Meta, there are about five pages worth just tag edit’s of his. Please don’t do that.

If questions pop up due to edits, feel free to add a relevant tag to them. If they pertained to a historical event, just let them be.

Comment: Don't worry, Jan, I was just kidding about the "free rein" bit. :-)

Comment: @hBy2Py Hadn’t even read the comment =D

Answer (score -1):

**If you DISLIKE the idea of [site-cleanup](/questions/tagged/site-cleanup), UPVOTE THIS ANSWER.**